# Invalid column name in excel works in SQL

Tags: excel, sql-server-2008

I have a query that I wrote using Query Analyzer. It works in the Analyzer but when I run it in Excel I get an invalid column name error. the error does not list the entire column name. If I put square brackets around the entire column name the error lists the entire column name.

If i run the code as follows.

```
Select
     tblarInvoice.shipfromlocation
  From
     tblarInvoice
  Where  
     tblarInvoice.dateshipped >= '10/01/2014'
```

I get the error of:
Invalid column name'shipfrom'

If I run the code with square brackets around it i get the error of:

Invalid column name'shipfromlocation'

Comment: connecting in with the same IDs?  One may have permission the other may not.  Same database? could be different environments and the field isn't in that environment yet?

Comment: Yes, I am connecting with the same id's. In fact if I use other columns from the same table the query runs fine. it only errors when I use the shipfromlocation column.

Comment: Likely something to do with the driver being used.  Perhaps there's a limit on column length; Try and alias the column Name to something shorter.  It may also have trouble with the name 'FROM' in the column name. Could you create a view in the database that selects from the table but aliases the column name driver may parse the SQL see FROM think it's a reserved word and give up.  The [] may put you beyond a 30 character limit as well... so ... try something different use column name alias and  or select from the view? `SELECT tblarInvoice.shipfromlocation as sfl...`

Comment: xQbert, creating a view and using an alias worked! I tried using an alias in the original query and it did not work. I wonder why it works that way.

Comment: excellent!  Answer below building on comments.  The fact it worked in query analyzer led me to believe that it had to be a driver problem.  the overall simplicity of the query means it had to be something non-standard, not a syntax error.  Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Likely something to do with the driver being used.

Perhaps there's a limit on column length. 
Try and alias the column Name to something shorter.

It may also have trouble with the name 'FROM' in the column name.

Could you create a view in the database that selects from the table but aliases the column name .

The driver may parse the SQL see FROM think it's a reserved word and give up. The [] may put you beyond a 30 character limit as well... so ... try something different use column name alias and or select from the view?

`SELECT tblarInvoice.shipfromlocation as sfl`

Root Cause is one of two things or a combination:
When processing the SQL string the Driver sees "FROM" and throws an error
When you wrap the name in [] it extends the field name to be > 30 characters which in some drivers is a limit.

You could isolate root cause by altering the alias on the view to be something like sFROMLocation  If you get an error you know the driver has probelms parsing column names with FROM in them.
If you alter it to sFroLocation does it then work?

Additionally you could set the column name to tblarinvoiceshipfrolocationtest if an error is returned you know that column names > 30 are problems for the driver being used.

then change it to 
tblarinvoiceshipfrolocationtst if it works then you know a 31 length name doesn't work. a 30 does.  again evidence driver can't support column names longer than 30 characters.

Just depends if you want to get to root cause :P